# c++ MFC compile error "C2470: 'CMySink' : looks like a function definition, but there is no parameter list; skipping apparent body"

Tags: c++, com, mfc

c++ MFC compile error

error C2470: 'CMySink' : looks like a function definition, but there is no parameter list; skipping apparent body   d:\faxmanager\faxmanager\mysink.cpp 34

.h file

```
class CMySink : public CCmdTarget
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CMySink)
...

protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()    
     void OnJobAdded(FAXCOMEXLib::IFaxServer *pFaxServer, BSTR bstrJobId);
    ...
};
```

.cpp file

```
BEGIN_DISPATCH_MAP(CMySink, CCmdTarget)
  DISP_FUNCTION (CMySink ,"OnOutgoingJobAdded", OnJobAdded, VT_EMPTY, VTS_I4 VTS_BSTR)
END_DISPATCH_MAP()

void CMySink:OnJobAdded(FAXCOMEXLib::IFaxServer *pFaxServer,  BSTR bstrJobId) 
{ 

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void CMySink:OnJobAdded
```

should be

```
void CMySink::OnJobAdded
```